# Navigation component not getting re rendered with stage change in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, computed-properties

When a user updates their username in the EditAccount component, the username is updated in the EditAccount component and in vuex store but not in the Navigation component even though stage change is updated to the new user name.

The problem is that the user is seing thier old user name in Navigation component and a updated user name in the EditAccount component and they don't match.

How can I Re render the Navigation component with the new user name?

Below is the the code for user the data in the Navigation component.

Store vuex: index.js

```
const store = createStore({
  // strict: true,
  state: {
    user: null,
    authIsReady: false,
    //
    // current category
    playlistCategory: null,
  },
  //
  getters: {
    getUser(state) {
      return state.user;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    //
    // update playlist category
    updatePlaylistCategory(state, payload) {
      state.playlistCategory = payload;
    },
    //
    //
    setUser(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload;
    },
    //
    setAuthIsReady(state, payload) {
      state.authIsReady = payload;
    },
    //
  },
  actions: {
    async editUser(context, payload) {
      const { displayNewName, displayNewEmail } = payload;
      await updateUserDetails(displayNewName, displayNewEmail);
      // get current user
      const responseUser = await user;
      // set user state
      context.commit('setUser', responseUser);
    },
  },
```

NavBar.vue

```
  // vue3 and composition api
  setup() {
    // store
    const store = useStore()
    //
    const { error, logout, isPending } = useLogout()
    const router = useRouter()
    //
    // getters
    const user = computed(() => {
      return store.getters.getUser.displayName
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `set` and `get` property:

```js
const user = computed({
    get: store.state.user,
    set: (val) => store.state.user = val
});
```

Comment: I tried below but it did not help: 

`const user = computed({ 
get: () => { 
return store.state.user 
}, 
set: (updatedUser) => { 
store.state.user = updatedUser 
}, 
})`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a getter instead acessing the value directly in the state

Getter for user:

```
export function getUser(state){
 return state.getUser
}
```

and in the component import the getter like this:

```
<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('*theStoreName*',['getUser'])
    },
    watch: {
        getUser: function(){
            //Should be possible to see when the getUser changes here
            console.log(this.getUser)
        }
        
    }
}
</script>
```

**Note**: You have *theStoreName* for the store name you're using

Maybe the problem is that the store name is missing, or when you did `store.state.user` you're acessing the store? If it is it, then you should try to inform the variable you're trying to access, like If it is, like `store.state.user.name`, with the getter it would be: `getUser.name`

Comment: Thanks for your message, but it did not help.
I added the code in the original post.